# unitialized constant for gem published on rubygems.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just published my first gem named digup at rubygems.org. I added it to gem 'digup' to gemfile and ran bundle install. But when i ran rails s command, it stops by saying

```
/home/rohan/digup_test/config/environments/development.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Digup (NameError)
```

Below are the line added in development.rb

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Digup::Setting.options = {
     :response_type => [:js, :html, :json],
     :cursor_info => false
    }
  end
```

Below is gemspec file of gem

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'digup/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "digup"
  spec.version       = Digup::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Rohan Pujari"]
  spec.email         = ["rohanpujaris@gmail.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{Debug by printing data directly as html or in web console}
  spec.summary       = %q{Digup allows you to debug your application by printing everything in html page. Digup have diffrent logging mode file, db logging and logging debug data directly to console and html page}
  spec.homepage      = "https://github.com/rohanpujaris/digup"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"

  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'rails', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.20'
end
```

I have added middleware in the gem which also doesn't shows up when using rake middleware command from terminal. I am using Rails 3.1.6 and ruby 1.9.3 with rvm.

Rails server and gem works fine when installed from local folder by specifying path as gem 'digup', :path => '~/digup'. Here is the source code of gem https://github.com/rohanpujaris/digup. Please can anybody help me out

Comment: The gem you've published is essentially empty - there's nothing there other than the specification. Not sure why though

Comment: Thanks buddy. I didn't saw that. I pushed it again and its now working.